# How to file NYS Taxes for Deceased

Tags: united-states, income-tax, new-york

IRS has straightforward instructions to file Federal Taxes for Deceased, but I failed to find the same for New York State.

When I google, "new york state deceased taxpayer", it gives "Instructions for Form ET-706
New York State Estate Tax Return", https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/et/et706i.pdf

But this is for someone with Estate Tax.

Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are trying to file the last IT-201 for an individual.

To my understanding the rules are similar for filing of an individual's last Federal tax return (due date of filing, what to file, who can file, etc.).

The Instructions for IT-201 does have a section for [deceased tax payers](https://www.tax.ny.gov/forms/current-forms/it/it201i.htm#deceased-taxpayers).

Searching for the word 'decedent' in https://www.tax.ny.gov/forms/current-forms/it/it201i.htm can help identify items to check in the NYS tax instructions.

Comment: Yes, filing as in individual. Thank you for these links. i struggled for days to find this information.